# Can we downgrade from a IO1 SSD to a GP2 SSD ebs volume in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am currently using a gp2 elastic volume and i wanted to upgrade to io1 volume in AWS for high iops for a few days now i wanted to know once i upgrade it then after a few days will i be able to downgrade it back to gp2 and if it is possible,is their any loss of data or any such scenario possible please help.

I know how to upgrade the volume but i am not sure about downgrading it so if anyone has ever tried it please help.

current volume: gp2

i used this command to upgrade:

```
aws ec2 modify-volume --volume-type io1 --iops 10000 --size 200 --volume-id vol-1
```

what should be the appropriate way to downgrade it.

Comment: just try modify-volume after take a snapshot.

Comment: lacking privileges therefore i cannot experiment so that is why i am asking.

Answer (score 5):

Although changing from gp2 to io1 might seem like an upgrade and changing back from io1 to gp2 might seem like a downgrade, the truth is more nuanced, because each volume type¹ has certain use cases where it is the best choice.

As a rule, you can change from any volume type to any other volume type, with only one class of [documented](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/modify-volume-requirements.html) volume type-related exceptions, due to mounting and size constraints on st1 and sc1 volumes.

So changing from one type to another type is generally a non-issue, but the same thing is not true of size.  It is not possible to make an EBS volume smaller.  They can only be made larger.

EBS volume modifications are a safe operation, and can even be done "hot" with the disk still in use... but as a matter of best practice, you should always take an EBS snapshot before attempting a modification.

---

¹*each volume type* except standard.  I can't think of any case where a standard volume would be the best choice.

Comment: Do I lose data if I change the storage type from io1 to gp2?

Comment: @MD.AtiqurRahman They recommend that you create a snapshot before requesting the change, but changes to EBS volumes are designed to be done hot and live.  You can modify volumes with the instance still running and the disk in active use and you should not lose data or have any disruption.   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/requesting-ebs-volume-modifications.html